Samsung Electric range triple burner not working
The triple burner isn't going on for my Samsung NE59N6650SS.
Using the AstroAI Multimeter Tester 2000 Counts Digital Multimeter. I put the dial on 200 and tested the element. The element tested good.
Brown to orange 46 ohms
Brown to yellow 44 ohms
Brown to blue 62 ohms
The infinite switch has some burning on it and the red connector for it also has some browning. I did set the multimeter to the continuity dial and the audio buzzed for continuity with 000 reading on the screen(if that matters) but there's burning on it and on the red molex connector white cap, so I am thinking it's the switch.
The element I was 100% confident I could change.(doesn’t appear to be the problem though).
The element switch I'm 100% confident I could change.
The actually molex connector into the switch that I think may be above me. Looks like a lot of wires on the harness. Is this something a novice can do or am I better off hiring someone?
The clips itself looks fine. It's the plastic casing that was browning and now cracked off. Can I use with a new switch and just wrap with electric tape or shrink wrap? I'm including some photos. Would truly appreciate any help. I thank you for your time!
https://postimg.cc/gallery/g0392ZZ

Might want to put the images here so easier to see.  I would try sanding off all the brown burn marks everywhere first... :) There should be some more multimeter tests you can run on the infinite switch?

Sorry wasn't sure how to put photos here. What other multimeter test do you mean? I'm ok with ordering the switch and if it ends up not being the problem just returning it, but I think it is the problem. My concern is that the molex crimp connector(idk if that's actually the name) that plugs into the switch the plastic casing broke off cause it was a little burnt. Now if I were to plug the wire into the switch it no longer has a protected casing.  Just wondering if I can just wrap in electric tape or shrink wrap? Or am I gonna have to hire someone to redo the wire?

There is special high temperature shrink wrap. You would need to use that. That connection is not supposed to get very hot but presumably it would be too hot for simple standard heatshrink.

Any suggestion on what I should use? Maybe point me to something on amazon?

You could test the wire tabs of the infinite switch? https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/241951/electric-stove-burner-starts-and-stays-on-high-on-lowest-setting-infinite-switc  Another test you could do would be continuity from the "power in" tab all the way to the element.  In my head the suspect would either be the one bad connection or the infinity switch.  You could ascertain if it's the infinity switch by cleaning (sanding) both sides of the red wire connection and just wrapping it with electrical tape temporarily, then trying it out...was the white plug broken underneath?

Burnt marks usually are a sign of a loose or dirty connection.  There are Terminal Removal Tool Kits sold to remove connectors from the blocks.  Taking pictures and labelling the wires before removal helps a lot for replacing them after.  Replacing the connectors might be all that is needed, unless the switch after testing also shows problems.

There's some burring on the p1 slot of the switch. That's why I'm assuming it's the switch. While the plastic case of the molex plug for that slot was burnt the actual molex doesn't appear damaged. Gonna try a new switch and since the molex no longer has a case & is bare I'm gonna use 4:1 High Flame Retardant Heat Shrink Tubing to protect it. That doesn't work then I guess I'll hire someone.

Post back your answer here when you figure it out :)

I took off some of the burned corrosion off of the p1 pin on the switch just out of curiosity and the burner starting working again. So it was definitely that. It's working again. Would this switch be safe to use or I should replace it anyway?

Apparently the reason for the large plastic sleeves might be to cover the large connectors: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/306747/what-is-the-purpose-of-long-plastic-sleeve-tubes-around-connections-in-appliance/306748#306748 (I used some of your pictures to ask that question :) So you should be OK to reuse I assume.

Switch looks like it would clean up ok to me. Sand paper all sides back to brass like the other tabs. Here's how to clean the female side of the connection: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/306597/how-to-clean-a-female-quick-disconnect-spade-connector Then crimp it a tiny bit more for a secure connection...pliers. heat shrink wouldn't hurt but might not be absolutely necessary... Flipping it upside down might be an option but might not be actually needed though. Feel free to answer your own question here or I will, cheers!

You can use a multimeter to check between the tabs on the infinity switch if it's bad or not.  At least that ascertained that one was bad for me once.
The white plug (pics) being broken and "burned looking" probably implies it got loose at some point and had some sparks.  Try to cleanup that connection and also get a good tight fit.  Should be OK if you can get some good cleaned up surfaces contacting firmly.  It's broken but not in danger of contacting other surfaces (could surround it with some high temp shrink insulation but it's pretty isolated so...)
I've had some of those connectors fail on me recently as well.  Wonder if industry could come up with a better connection mechanism...please?
