How to clean a female quick disconnect spade connector
I'm used to sanding electrical connections to clean them up before reusing them, but I am not sure how to clean a female disconnect like the kind used in appliances.

Ideas/thoughts?

What's the objective?  And why does the boot look burned?

This swamp cooler it's from was showing some weirdness like occasionally tripping it's breaker and occasionally not starting right (buzzing) or staying on even when the control panel showed no lights.  I'm looking for a solid connection to eliminate that connection as a failure variable... It's suspect since it's  the only one that has that browning.  Possibly from being loose? :)

I noticed some other people run into discoloration like this in these connectors too, so was curious what a canonical repair option would be: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/306125/looking-for-some-advice-on-an-samsung-ne59n6650ss-electric-range?noredirect=1#comment649166_306125

Was the connector loose and wobbly when you disconnected it? Does the fan turn freely by hand when disconnected from the mains?

It did feel a little loose like you could rock it back and forth, however it kinda felt that way on all of its sibing connectors as well so I am not certain what was happening.  The fan does turn OK, I have a suspicion the buzzing is caused when the fan is trying to start on "high" as the motor has a history of weirdness with its high mode not starting quite right...the breaker tripping is possibly unrelated to that...

The design of this type of connector, called a spade connector for the shape of the male side is such that it is more or less self-cleaning. The action of pushing the part shown in the photo onto the flat blade of the male connector results an a mild abrading of the two surfaces.
You can see this on the male portion as a lighter color line coincident to the contact stripe of the female connector.
If you are experiencing corrosion, use an appropriate mild base or mild acid to clean it away. If the corrosion is so severe that you observe pitting, it may be advisable to replace the connector, although that's a rare circumstance unless the connector is used in a battery environment.

Image above resulted from DuckDuckGo search for "spade connector."

So clean the male end, then connect them a few times would you say, to clean it?

I don't see any corrosion. And a mild acid or base could cause some, unless it is properly neutralized after.

I have never seen this called a spade connector. This is a quick-connect or faston connector; spade connectors are something very different.

You sleuthed it right, the picture was actually after dipping it in some vinegar...I should rinse with water :) I still wanted to clean it up as best possible and show the discolored boot as my initial reason for wanting to do so... :)

@MichaelHarvey They are one of many types of crimp terminal; "crimp" just refers to how they're attached to the wire, not the shape of the end opposite the wire. "spade connector" to me (USian electrical engineer) means one of these, a forked metal terminal designed to be inserted around a screw which is then tightened down on it to hold it in place. I suppose this must be either a US/UK divide thing, or an EE/(some other field) divide--I'll have to be mindful of it in the future, to avoid miscommunication!

@MichaelHarvey It probably is a US/UK thing, then, because Digikey, another one of the main industry suppliers and one based in the US, calls the one I linked a spade terminal, and the ones in the question "quick connects" or "quick disconnects".

At my local US hardware store they seem to label them as "female disconnect" "quick connector" or "quick connect" which I'll admit are all basically confusing LOL :)

You don't, that's a wiping contact that cleans itself when mated or disconnected.
It appears to be in good condition, the visible copper conductor ends show no sign of oxidation and while the discolouration might possibly suggest a problem I've seen far worse with transparent sleeve over a neon.
I've assumed that the insulation is braided, hence what we're seeing at the stripped end is scrunched up fibres.

+1.  When you don't know what's wrong, sometimes it's efficient to just go through the motions of fixing the most common problems without diagnosing them.   But cleaning spade connectors is not the most common cure to anything.  I wouldn't pursue this at all, but if you must, AT LEAST diagnose it.  Run the thing with the cover off (when nobody else is around to become electrocuted) and monitor this connector for sparks or heat.  Try jiggling it (without touching the metal) to see if that provokes the "weirdness".

And I highly suspect most people don't take these out properly and just yank on the wire, which isn't going to help.

It looks like braided wire with non-melted insulation, hard to see in that picture :)

This was possibly contributing to a breaker breaking occasionally, worth removing as a question mark anyway, and it was the only one that showed signs of burning...I doubt that just re-inserting it would have fixed, if it was loose...in this case it was really hard to pull off and yet might have been an issue...It's like these connectors get flakey somehow sometimes?

@rogerdpack "really hard to pull off"... you /did/ release the clip, didn't you? There's a potential problem with this sort of connector in that they come in several different thicknesses, a a quick squish with a pair of pliers is no substitute to the right one having been used in the first place. They /can/ go bad but it's unusual, and an apparent problem with one is usually an indication of a real problem elsewhere.

There's a clip?  I'll have to keep an eye out for that.  I agree getting a matching replacement connector makes sense (if you replace them).  They seem a common point of failure, could imply problems elsewhere as well I suppose, but cleaning them up seems to have "fixed" some problems I've run into (FWIW).  Peace!

@rogerdpack yes, on the one shown in the OP photo. Folded back from the entry end, with an actuator tab at 45deg towards the crimped connector.

Sanding any contact surface will likely sand off the plating of the metal that is intended to mate with the other surface.
With spade connectors, being tight is everything. If the connector presses together without a great deal of resistance, making it very tight, you can use pliers to bend the receptacle end you show in the photo to make it tighter.
You can also use an "electronic" lubricant like CRC 2-26 or any brand dielectric grease (preferred in this case) on the connection to keep oxygen and moisture out.

Adding a grease seems like a good idea too, in case the connection gets looser later the grease might help? :)

tl;dr - Replace this crimp connector.
This is (in my opinion) an X-Y question - you ask how to clean the connector, but you really want to ensure it connects properly as part of troubleshooting/fixing.
I think the dullness of the connector is due to oxidation of the protective tinning, either due to age or overheating; the boot discolouration hint strongly at overheating.  However, the contact surface of this type of connector is not visible in the picture (it's the end of the curls facing the spade) and the visible oxidation is irrelevant and there is no point in cleaning it; I've seen some still-good connectors that look at least this bad on older equipment (40 years and more) where it was just age.  Also, the location of the mating face makes it difficult to get to, and it's a wiping connector anyway so self-cleaning if the connector is correctly tight.  If you really want a shiny clean connector, the only way would be to replace it.
The oxidation and browning of the boot strongly suggest moderate overheating, which can cause annealing of the contact springing, which can cause poor contact force and high resistance, which in turn causes more overheating.  In extremis this could cause arcing (tripping arc fault breakers) or non-connection  preventing operation (and sensitivity to being moved or jolted - if it required a whack of the side to get it working, this is another indicative symptom).
If the connector is too easy to push on/off (can be pushed with one finger fairly easily) the connector springing is too loose, and something needs to be done.  It's possible to fix by squeezing the 'curls' on the connector down towards the back, but take care not to squeeze too much  - to avoid closing it up too much, slide it onto the spade by a couple of mm (less than a tenth inch) and squeeze with pliers to close the gap somewhat at the crimp end of the connector, so that fully inserting it forces the curl open again.  If there was not much resistance when squeezing, that's an indication that the connector has been annealed by overheating, and the only true fix would be to replace the connector, although the above procedure will work for diagnostic purposes.
These crimps and cheap crimpers are available as a kit at many automotive stores and large supermarkets; I've even seen them in a Pound shop (Dollar store).

I'd give this +3 if I could; it's the right answer to the actual issue.

Your advice about squeezing the connector is perfect. But yeah, replace it. :-)  +1

Definitely replace in this case (+1) but check for underlying causes and damage to/near the mating part.  Squeezing is useful if they're frequently disconnected; I use them on my bike dynamo lighting systems where they function well despite wet conditions causing the exposed plating to get very dull

This is a good idea especially if the little middle "bubble" mating surface (that's on some of them) may  have gotten flat over time...

Yup. Snip it off and crimp on a new one. How long are you gonna spend cleaning it?

So I didn't notice this but turns out that the space "between" the curling side-grabbers (in the middle) is also a point of contact, so if that's looking burned you could sand it.  Also recrimp the curling grabbers (with them disconnected, pliers works) and clean the male end (sand it).  Run it through a couple times for the self-cleaning that others have mentioned, recrimp again :)
I also wonder (if it's the kind with a tiny bubble in the middle) if you could push the bubble in a bit...
