What is the purpose of long plastic sleeve tubes around connections in appliances?
It appears this particular stove top uses long plastic tubes around its connectors to the infinity switch.


Why are those there?  Why not just connect into it directly with a disconnect?

As an aside, I really don't like the look of that 240Vac 15A connector.  I'm not an expert, but I feel reasonably certain that those tabs aren't adequate to carry that kind of power, as evidenced by the discoloration of the insulating sleeve.

The connections or "plastic tubes" as you refer to them perform 4 functions.
1- They have a "lock" that keeps the connections in place.
2-They are "indexed", or made to fit into only one particular connection. Therefore making the assembly at the factory more foolproof for the assembly workers.
3- The different colors are easier to identify the particular circuit when working with a wire diagram.
4- Possibly most important, they provide insulation so bare metal on the ends of wires is not exposed.

I believe that implicit in the question is why are they so long and tubular/sleeve shaped. All of your listed factors could be accomplished by a much shorter (more conventional) connector. So what's the reason for them being a long plastic sleeve tube (versus a short, solid connector)?

@R M, It could be 2 things.1- Longer makes it easier for the installers to grasp, especially if their hands  are gloved.  2- it is what is in stock for use and not economically sound to have shorter products for this instance.  Remember the manufacturer's goal is not to make it easy  / convenient for the homeowner to do repairs.

They're exactly long enough to cover the entirety of the spade (faston) connector inside, preventing accidental contact with live metal.

@R.M. they are typically not longer than they need to be. Look at the back of the black connector in the OP's 1st pic - there's metal right up to the back of the inside of the plastic. If the plastic were any shorter then the metal would be exposed.

The other thought I had is maybe they make it easier to insert the connection (more straight forward)?  Also maybe the connector is extra heavy duty large so they wanted to cover it, as discussed... :)

The added length may also provide some strain relief.  If an assembler bend the wire sharply right at the crimp, that would put a lot of strain on the connection.  If the housing requires a bit of straight wire and the installer then made a sharp connection, a some of the strain is offloaded from the connection.  Note that the white connector in the first photo seems to have a plastic collar where the wires emerge.

Wow, there is way too much interest in the insulators for wires inside an appliance here.
